# Will GitHub allow a merge or rebase of a "branch of another branch"?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

I have a unique scenario where I'm working with one other person on a project (that comprises a single GitHub repo) and I'm responsible for the design, some development & doing the code reviews + PR merges. I want to try and stick with GitFlow as much as possible here, and I only want to be the one who can merge PRs from feature branches back into develop. So the auth model I'm going with (at least tentatively) is:

- I have read/write access to `master` and `develop`
- The other dev only has read access to `develop`

So now we're in an interesting flow here:

1. The other dev cut a feature branch (say `feature/12345`) off of `develop` and worked on it for a few days then pushed his changes to GitHub
2. It was going to take me several days to get around to code reviewing his work and I didn't want him to be held up, so I had him cut the next feature branch (say `feature/23456`) off of his first feature branch and begin working.
3. Over the next several days I got around to code reviewing `feature/12345`, made some changes to it and then pushed those changes. At the same time he worked on `feature/23456`.
4. Satisfied with `feature/12345`, I merged it into `develop` and asked him to pull my changes into his `feature/23456`.

Will he be able to create a PR to merge `feature/23456` into `develop`, or will this "branch of a branch" scenario screw things up with GitHub? Will I be able to actually do the merge, or do I need to do some kind of rebase (if so what do the commands for this look like)?

Answer (score 1):

If your colleague hasn't yet pushed `feature/23456` to GitHub, he should pull updated `develop` and rebase feature branch on top of it:

- check out `feature/23456`
- perform `git rebase develop`

That's it, now his feature branch looks like it was always growing from the top of the `develop`.

If rebasing isn't an option, most probably, git will be able to handle merging branch of another branch just fine without additional magic, but can't say for sure.

If for some reason things go bad way, there is always dumb and not elegant, but bullet-proof solution. It's always possible to create new branch from `develop` and simply `cherry-pick` all necessary commits from `feature/23456` into it, making "fresh duplicate" of it to keep things simple.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the thoughtful answer @nnovich-OK (+1). Two quick followup questions for you if you don't mind: **(1)** if in Step 4 he pulls in the changes I made to `feature/12345` into his `feature/23456`, then why would he need to pull the updated `develop` like you say? And **(2)** can you please just confirm that he can `git rebase develop` even *without* write permissions to `develop`? Thanks again!

Comment: **(2)** Rebasing `feature/23456` branch doesn't anyhow affect `develop`, so it shouldn't require write permission. It's kind of replanting: feature branch initially grew from some commit on `feature/12345`, you take this branch and "replant", so now it grows from the latest commit in `develop`, while `develop` itself isn't affected.

Comment: **(1)** Well, I'm actually not fully clear on how exactly dev took changes of `feature/12345` into `feature/23456`. I'm aiming at the most clear scheme, where `feature/23456` pretends, that it was branched from `develop`, which already has `feature/12345` integrated. For this case you pull `develop` (so it has all `feature/12345` stuff in it) and do a rebase of `feature/23456` so it pretends to be branched from `develop` with `feature/12345` integrated.